# Parse.com Save object as Date type

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am currently trying to save an object as the date data type, however it only saves it as a string. I read that parse.com needs the format to be in ISO8601 and to make sure I got it correct I used the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) library to ensure that it would be. Here is my current code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data[i].body.und.length; i++) {
            article = new Articles(),
            content = data[i];
            article.set("body", content.body.und[0].value);
            article.set("vid", content.vid);
            article.set("title", content.title);
            var epochTime = content.created;
            var dateObject = moment.unix(content.created).format();
            article.set("dateCreated", dateObject);

            articles.push(article);
          }
```

Comment: Just a note: You don't need to add a "dateCreated" column. Parse already adds a "createdAt" field when you save an object.

Comment: Oh, I know that, I am actually pulling an external JSON file which contains articles and the date created refers to the date the article was submitted. I probably should have specified that to be clearer, sorry.